# Weak strong lower semi continuity for integrals

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $f$ a measurable fonction lower semi continuous from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. Consider the folowing space $V(0,T)$ endowed with the weak topology *, in the sens $\nu_n$ converge to $\nu$ if and only for any real mesurable function $f$ defined on $[0,T]$,

$$\int_{[0,T]}f(s)\nu_n(ds)\to\int_{[0,T]}f(s)\nu(ds)$$.

I want to show that the following map
$$\phi:=\begin{cases}\mathcal{C}[0,T]\times V(0,T)\mapsto \mathbb{R} \\
(x,\nu)\to \displaystyle\int_{[0,T]}f(x(s))\nu(ds)
\end{cases}$$
is lower semi continuous, where $\mathcal{C}[0,T]$ is the set of continous functions defined on $[0,T]$, endowed with the classical uniform norm.

Thank you for help.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I forgotten, that the set for the weak convergence are the set of bounded measurable function on $[0,T]$, for the moment nothing special, only writing for a sequence $x_n,\nu_n$ converging to $x,\nu$ $$\int_{[0,T]}f(x_n(s))d\nu_n(s)-\int_{[0,T]}f(x(s))d\nu(s)\ge \int_{[0,T]}(f(x_n(s))-f(x(s))d\nu_n(s)+int_{[0,T]}f(x(s))d\nu_n(s)-\int_{[0,T]}f(x(s))d\nu(s)$$ Obviously, the last term is easy at the limit, i dont know how to deal with the first term $\int_{[0,T]}(f(x_n(s))-f(x(s))d\nu_n(s)$.